Cost of Goods Sold Calculation
I am trying to calculate cost of goods sold with the following logic:
I have two tables: SaleActions and PurchaseActions with the following structure:
PurcahseActions: PurchaseId, PurchaseDate, PurchaseLineId, ItemId, Quantity, Price.
SaleActions:SaleId, SaleDate, SaleLineId, ItemId, Quantity, Price.
Here is an example:
Aug 1 : 60 units of X item is purchased at 1 USD rate
Aug 2 : 5 units of X item is purchased at 2 USD rate
Aug 5: 63 units of X item is sold at 1.5 USD.
Using this data I trying to come up with the following result set:



SaleId
SaleLineId
PurchaseId
PurchaseLineId
Quantity
Price




3741
24872
21904
23649
60
1


3741
24872
21904
23649
3
2



This is what I have created up to now :
WITH RankedPurchases AS (SELECT PurchaseId,
                                PurchaseDate,
                                LineId                                                                                AS PurchaseLineId,
                                ItemId,
                                Quantity,
                                Price,
                                SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY PurchaseDate, PurchaseId)            AS CumulativePurchaseQuantity,
                                SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY PurchaseDate, PurchaseId) - Quantity AS PreviousCumulativePurchaseQuantity
                         FROM @PurchaseActions),
     RankedSales AS (SELECT SaleId,
                            SaleDate,
                            LineId                                                                        AS SaleLineId,
                            ItemId,
                            Quantity,
                            SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY SaleDate, SaleId)            AS CumulativeSaleQuantity,
                            SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY SaleDate, SaleId) - Quantity AS PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity
                     FROM @SaleActions),
     MatchedSales AS (SELECT s.SaleId,
                             s.SaleLineId,
                             p.PurchaseId,
                             p.PurchaseLineId,
                             s.ItemId,
                             s.Quantity                                                                                    AS SaleQuantity,
                             p.Quantity                                                                                    AS PurchaseQuantity,
                             p.Price,
                             s.PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity,
                             p.PreviousCumulativePurchaseQuantity,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.SaleId, s.SaleLineId ORDER BY p.PurchaseDate, p.PurchaseId) AS RowNum
                      FROM RankedSales s
                               JOIN RankedPurchases p ON s.ItemId = p.ItemId
                      WHERE p.CumulativePurchaseQuantity > s.PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity
                        AND p.PreviousCumulativePurchaseQuantity < s.CumulativeSaleQuantity)
SELECT SaleId,
       SaleLineId,
       PurchaseId,
       PurchaseLineId,
       CASE
           WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN
               CASE
                   WHEN SaleQuantity <= PurchaseQuantity THEN SaleQuantity
                   ELSE PurchaseQuantity
                   END
           ELSE
               CASE
                   WHEN SaleQuantity - (PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity - PreviousCumulativePurchaseQuantity) <= PurchaseQuantity
                       THEN SaleQuantity - (PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity - PreviousCumulativePurchaseQuantity)
                   ELSE PurchaseQuantity
                   END
           END AS Quantity,
       Price
FROM MatchedSales
ORDER BY ItemId, SaleId, SaleLineId, RowNum

However my result shows quantity as 60 and 5 instead of 60 and 3. The complete query with minimum-reproducible-data :
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=0332881c-690e-4ca9-9e22-5cb255bf74c9.

Questions need to be stand alone I e. Your fiddle contents need to be included within your question.

And how does the cost of goods get calculated, FIFO, LIFO, weighted? SO ain't a free coding service website, you need to demonstrate some effort and not just write some words and watch people go at it

hi @DaleK thanks for the feedback and edit. I edited the query fully.

@siggemannen thanks for the feedback. I updated the description with all the necessary details.

This is a fairly common overlapping-range query. Although your overlap condition check is correct (End1 > Start2 && Start1 < End2), your overlap length (quantity) calculation is incorrect.
You can calculate the correct overlap quantity as LEAST(End1, End2) - GREATEST(Start1, Start2). For your query, this would be:
LEAST(CumulativePurchaseQuantity, CumulativeSaleQuantity)
    - GREATEST(PreviousCumulativePurchaseQuantity, PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity)
    AS Quantity

The LEAST() and GREATEST() functions are new in SQL Server 2022. For earlier versions, you can calculate the equivalent using a CASE expression or IIF() function:
IIF(CumulativePurchaseQuantity < CumulativeSaleQuantity,
    CumulativePurchaseQuantity, CumulativeSaleQuantity)
    - IIF(PreviousCumulativePurchaseQuantity > PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity,
          PreviousCumulativePurchaseQuantity, PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity)
    AS Quantity

The above requirs that you expose the PreviousCumulativeSaleQuantity and CumulativePurchaseQuantity values in the MatchedSales CTE results, or alternately move this quantity calculation to the inside of that CTE. You may actually find that CTE is no longer needed, if you combine its contents with the final select.
Sample results (with some extra test data and different columns):



SaleId
SaleQuantity
PurchaseId
PurchaseQuantity
AppliedQuantity
From#
To#




1
63
1
60
60
0
60


1
63
2
5
3
60
63


2
15
2
5
2
63
65


2
15
3
10
10
65
75


2
15
4
20
3
75
78



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
